# HTML5 - Getting Started Using Offline Storage

Tags: javascript, html, firebug, offline-storage

I am following [a tutorial](http://www.mobilehtml5.com/post/401111526/tutorial-your-first-mobile-html5-app-offline-storage) to setup Offline Storage.  I picked a compatible browser, FireFox 4.0.1.  According to the Site that is all I need.  Yet, somehow it does not work.

My code blows up in Javascript on this line.

`var db = window.openDatabase("scores", "", "Previous Scores", 1024 * 1000);`

I don't know what error is being thrown.  I F11 to try to step into this line in Firebug, but nothing happens after that.

I am surprised this line is called without checking if the DB exists (I didn't install SQL express I guess it comes with the browser now nor did I setup the DB table).

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: My Firefox 4.0.1(Build identifier: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1) don't seem to implement it. Can't find in the site you refers a mention to FF 4.0.1.

Comment: @Prusse - This is where I get my compatibility information:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194784/which-browsers-support-html5-offline-storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are confusing the [(abandoned) Web SQL Database API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) for the [Web Storage API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/). The SQL API is only supported in Safari, while Web Storage (also called localStorage) is widely supported.